# Regex to get timestamp even if it starts with newline

Tags: regex, logging

I am trying to get each timestamp in a log entries using this regex:

```
/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}/
```

However in this sample, I am not able to get the second entry. I suspect that it is because of the second has `\r\n`.

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS log message here
  cont.
  cont.

YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS log message here
```

Comment: Which language are you running? Did you enable the multiline `m` modifier?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm using this regex in nxlog to parse multiline log entries. I use this regex to identify the headerline. However when I tried running this, it doesn't capture the second log entry, it treats as one.

Comment: try `/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}/m`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm sorry but I already tried that. NXLog reads it every line, so in order for me to separate the second entry is I need to define a regex that will determine if I reach the second timestamp entry.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the regexp flavor you use, for example if it's javascript you need to provide `/gm` which is:

- g - perform a global match
- m - perform multiline matching

And I would correct your regexp a bit because in case of non valid date (like 2015-32-65) yours will match.

```
/^(\d{4})\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30|31)\s(0\d|1\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}/gm
```

You can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/nI3uO6/1

Comment: actually my goal is to capture the \n as well if it exist before the timestamp, is this possible?

Comment: As I told it's matter of the modifiers of the regex:  https://regex101.com/r/lP4wL6/2 - here I've added `\gm` and it matches all the strings on new lines. It it doesn't help then I did't get a question.